# What did Louise say to the Chinese President in the movie Arrival?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrival

In the movie Arrival, Loiuse, played by Amy Adams says something to the Chinese President, which he claims were his wife's words. I think she is speaking Mandarin but no subtitles are
provided. What did she say?

Comment: I thought it would have been a nice loop back to the beginning of the film if she'd quoted her own book, saying "in war, language is the first weapon we reach for". That would also make sense as "use weapon" was the alien phrase in question. That was my reasoning for him opting not to use subtitles.

Comment: Was he president? I only recall the title of General.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to the blog Thrill List;

> The sequence is even more challenging because we're never given the dialogue MacGuffin. Heisserer says Villeneuve debated whether or not to include subtitles for the line. The director opted to revel in the mystery. The writer wasn't as keen on keeping it a secret, and was happy to divulge. As he told the audience at Fantastic Fest, the line translates to: "In war there are no winners, only widows."
>
> "I worked so hard on the dialogue in Mandarin for Denis," Heisserer wrote on Reddit. "Spent weeks crafting the lines that he finally approved! And then that scoundrel goes and doesn't use subtitles in that scene. I guess there's something to be said there about the nature of language. And I love Denis. But he's also a mischievous fox."

Found at: https://www.thrillist.com/entertainment/nation/arrival-chinese-line-ending

Comment: Excellent! And you also answered my *future* question about why the English subtitles were not used for the Mandarin part.

Comment: Isn't it just an excellent bit of trivia!

Comment: isn't it a little short to be the only thing she said?

Comment: There should be something more: 驅子民理應憑赤勇淳愛。戰爭不成就英雄，只留下孤兒寡婦。"Lead the people with bravery and love. In war there are no winners, only widows." It's worth to mention that the Mandarin is so difficult to listen, even for the native speakers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it goes on the lines of, "War doesn't make winners, only widows."

Source: I had read it in some blog somewhere.

Comment: Can you add more details , like which blog

Comment: @Panther Well, [this one](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63978/32181) mentions it.

Comment: @Yakk buddy your link is pointing to this question only.